# WPF растянуть содержимое ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть ListBox, находится в Grid, между двумя row. Нужно растянуть ListBox на всю длину между этими rows. Причем независимо от количества записей в ListBox. Весь Grid должен помещаться на экране.

```
   <Grid Name="grdEmployeeFilterAndList">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="employeeListStackPanel" Grid.Row="0">
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox
  x:Name="lstEmployees"
  Grid.Row="1"
  Margin="6,5,8,0"
  SelectionChanged="lst_SelectionChanged"
  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PersonDataTemplate}"
  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
  Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle1}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="lstEmployees_DoubleClick"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ListBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="sc#1.000000, 0.769689, 0.831936, 1.000000" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

[image: ListBox]

**Решение:**
Решение найдено: проблема была в родительских элементах, которые растягивали окно. Разобралась с ними + помогло решение @Mirdin (которое работало бы и так, если бы не родительские элементы).

[image: ListBox2]

Comment: А где ваш код? Без кода сложно угадать, что вы сделали не так.

Comment: Окей, а как должно выглядеть? Если в списке 20000 элементов, должно окно растянуться по вертикали?

Comment: Само окно приложения не должно растягиваться, если список большой - появляется скрол. И этот список должен занять все оставшееся пространство между двумя row.

Comment: Тогда непонятно, чем вам не подходит ответ @Mirdin. ТОгда может покажите скриншот с проблемой.

Comment: На скришоте ListBox слева, сделано как посоветовал @Mirdin. В результате весь список уехал вниз за пределы экрана, а нужно чтобы остался в пределах, со скролом, т.к. внизу списка еще кнопки. Справа виден скрол всего окна приложения (которого естественно быть не должно если ListBox не будет вылазить за границы). В дизайнере студии все ок - ListBox аккуратно растянулся как и положено. Но при запуске получается иначе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так пробовали?

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Строка 1 займет все свободное по высоте место

Comment: ListBox содержит много элементов и в результате список скрывается где-то далеко внизу за экраном.

Comment: @Daria при использовании DockPanel - он сам будет скролиться как надо. Читайте другой ответ

Answer (score 2):

по моему, использование `grid` немного устарело. почему бы не использовать `DockPanel` со свойством `LastChildFill= true` ?

пример кода:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
   <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top" Fill="Aquamarine" MinHeight="100">  </Rectangle>
   <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Fill="Aqua" MinHeight="100"></Rectangle>
   <ListBox  Name="lisb" Margin="15" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue">
</ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Код генерации элементов:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   lisb.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = Convert.ToString(i) });
}
```

Пример отображения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: результат тот же, что и в предыдущем ответе - длинный список, уходящий в никуда.

Comment: @Daria вынужден не согласится. Сейчас обновлю ответ и скрин с автоматически сгенерироваными значениями

Comment: У меня наполнение происходит так: lstEmployees.ItemsSource = empl.CollectPersons(), возвращающий DataView. Если задать ListBox Height определенное значение, то да, скрол будет. Мой Grid является так же вложенным элементом еще у кучи других, видимо там проблема.

Comment: @Daria возможно и такой вариант. но все равно, использование `grid` - плохой вариант, как по мне